# Django Authentication: Creation of objects by users before registration

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I am working on a Django site where people create articles.  I'd like for people to be able to create an article as part of the registration process.  Here's the steps:

1. User hits "create article" without being registered or logged in.
2. User is directed to "create article" page that displays the form for creating the article.
3. After hitting the "submit" button on the "create article" form, the user is redirected to the registration / login page.
4. After the registration process or login, the article is saved under the user's ID.

I'm pretty new to Django, so here are the complications so far as I'm concerned:

- Do I save the object with an AnonymousUser as the author until after the login process?  How would I find the object again so that I can save it to the User after they're logged in or registered? Is there any kind of unique identifier in an AnonymousUser object?
- Should I pass the object through the registration process using URLs until the registration has taken place (to then save it)?  How does one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do what you're wanting to do. I would exclude the user from your create Article form, and set user to blank=True, null=True.

It's really up to you as to whether or not you just hold the article in session until after you create your user, or persist it to the database and assign the user after.

One benefit of holding it in session is that if the user abandons the registration process, you don't have a record in the database. I would recommend going this way, as it's easy to do, and you don't have to have any logic to clean up your db, should the user abandon the session.

To specifically answer your question about an anonymous user...no, there is not a unique identifier for an anonymous user. You can use sessions in Django to persist objects between views.

Answer (score 1):

**"Should I pass the object through the registration process using URLs until the registration has taken place (to then save it)? How does one do that?"**

The above suggestion that you have been made is the better solution but don't pass it to url. There are two ways to successfully do that.

1. You can pass the object through session variable so that no one will ever notice it instead of passing it to url.
2. You can determine which object you must get throught their IP address.